# Multiplying Elements in a Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am working on Linear Algebra and the topic is Vector Spaces/Subspaces. The elements of the subspace are defined as ([i], [j]). I am aware that one of the criteria for being a subspace includes that when you multiply an element with another element you get an element in that set. What exactly is meant by 'an element'? Is it ([i], [j]) * ([i_2], [j_2])?

Comment: In a vector space, you can only multiply vectors by scalars.  You can’t multiply vectors with each other.

Comment: There is no requirement for vector spaces that you need a defined multiplication *between* vectors.  The only requirement with regards to multiplication is that there is a *scalar* multiplication defined for a scalar times a vector.

Comment: This answer might be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/969737/155629

Comment: What do the square brackets mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the case for a subspace that "when you multiply an element with another element you get an element in that set," since a vector space does not require a "multiplication" of elements *in the vector space*. So, I have no definition of multiplication between $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$. It does require a definition of multiplication by elements of the ground field (that is, a definition of multiplication by scalars). Closure under scalar multiplication is what is required. So, if $(2,3)$ is in the subspace, so must be $2*(2,3) = (4,6)$.