# "V is a vector space over the field K"

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-fields

I can visualize what can a vector space be, but I am not able to comprehend exactly what is the field K here. Can someone explain in basic terms.
(or)
What exactly is a field here ?

Comment: K is mapping, I mean K maps set into V, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969720/what-is-the-main-difference-between-a-vector-space-and-a-field)

Comment: What do you think a vector space is without a field?

Comment: A field is an algebraic structure where there's a set with addition and multiplication satisfying certain properties (such as distributive, associative, commutative).  Classic examples are $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$, but there are also finite fields, such as integers modulo a prime.

Answer (score 3):

Not a formal definition, but perhaps something that will help your intuition.

The $n$ dimensional vector space you are most used to is the set of $n$-tuples $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ where each $a_i$ is a real number (an element of the field $\mathbb{R}$).

All the rules for vectors  work just as well if you restrict the coordinates to be rational numbers (the field $\mathbb{Q}$), or allow them to be complex numbers  (the field $\mathbb{C}$).

A field is just a set where the ordinary rules of arithmetic work. Any field will do for the coordinates for vectors. For example, they can just be $0$ or $1$, with arithmetic modulo $2$.